# Method does not have a signature compatible with delegate WaitCallback

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to start (it's my first time) a multithreading, and I wrote the code below, but I get am error:

> Method does not have a signature compatible with delegate

I've read the MSDN guide, and I've checked all parameters.

Where's the error?

```
Dim UxThr$, IdLxThr$, NumxThr%, RGxThr%, AxThr%
For CThr = 0 To LiTi.getUpperbound(1)
    UxThr = LiTi(3, CThr)
    IdLxThr = LiTi(0, CThr)
    NumxThr = CInt(LiTi(4, CThr))
    RGxThr = CInt(LiTi(1, CThr))
    AxThr = CInt(LiTi(2, CThr))

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf ThrP), UxThr, IdLxThr, NumxThr, RGxThr, AxThr)
Next
```

These are the parameters of the sub (address of):

```
Sub ThrP(ByVal UxThr$, ByVal IdLxThr$, ByVal NumxThr%, ByVal RGxThr%, ByVal AxThr%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) takes just a callback or callback with object.  You are passing in a number of variables, which is why you are getting that error.  Create a structure or class that contains the CThr, UxThr, IdLxThr, NumThr, etc members and pass a single instance of it into the QueueUserWorkItem method.  Additionally, you'll need to change your ThrP method so that it only contains one parameter (this newly created class or structure).

Example Code:

```
Public Structure YourStructure
    Public UxThr As String
    Public IdLxThr As String
    Public NumxThr As Integer
    Public RGxThr As Integer
    Public AxThr As Integer
End Structure

Public Sub ThrP(ByVal objInput As YourStructure)
    'Work Here
End Sub
```

Then your code in your question becomes:

```
    For CThr = 0 To LiTi.GetUpperBound(1)

        Dim objInput As YourStructure

        objInput.UxThr = LiTi(3, CThr)
        objInput.IdLxThr = LiTi(0, CThr)
        objInput.NumxThr = CInt(LiTi(4, CThr))
        objInput.RGxThr = CInt(LiTi(1, CThr))
        objInput.AxThr = CInt(LiTi(2, CThr))

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ThrP, objInput)

    Next
```

Comment: I was trying just that (I've passed an array) but I did not think it was something so silly! Thanks also for the example, I didn't know "structure": I'll study! ;)